# XamlParseException on ListPicker full mode wp8

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, exception, windows-phone-8

I've tried pretty much majority of the options suggested on this website but I might still be missing or some of you might know some other way.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker1" Margin="14,89,10,206" Grid.Row="1" FullModeHeader="FullMode" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="1" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="2" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="3" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="4" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="5" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="6" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="7" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="8" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="9" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="10" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="11" />
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="12" />
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Using Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit November 2010. The ListPicker works fine in normal or expanded modes (provided I reduce the number of items in the picker - it does not change to full mode automatically) but if I choose full mode in properties, it throws the following exception:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Comment: No idea, but it's suggested that if you are targetting a full wp8 app, you need to use the newer version of the toolkit! It has changed it's name and can be found here: http://phone.codeplex.com/

Comment: That worked! Also needed to change the list to <sys:String>1</sys:String> type. Can't answer my own question for 7 more h due to low reputation, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:
Update the toolkit and change the list type to 1

Comment: `<sys:String>1</sys:String>`